# I am getting endlessly API requests using SWR and Axios in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, swr

It is my first time of using SWR. Maybe I am wrongly implementing it. After implementing the SWR wrapper, I continued to get endless and repeated API call to the same endpoint. I saw this when I checked the Network tab of my browser:
Here is how I implemented it.

```
 const getProfile = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosPrivate.get<axiosGetCompanyProfile>(`/getcompany`, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { Authorization: `${state?.in_memory}` },
        });
        console.log(res?.data, 'pro')
        return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

const { data:fetchProfile, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/data', getProfile);


//fetch profile
 useEffect(()=>{

if(fetchProfile){
 dispatch({type: actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA, payload: fetchProfile });
return 
}
}, [isLoading]);
```

I noticed that the API calls happens whenever I leave the browser and returns. But from the look of things, it doesnt hit my server. So, why is it recalling it?
Here is a screnshot:

[request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFsAJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behaviour for data revalidation, in this case it's "revalidation on focus" ([link](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-focus)). You can disable it via the `revalidateOnFocus` option. If you want to fetch data just once you can use `useSWRImmutable` hook (`import useSWRImmutable from 'swr/immutable'`)

Check [this docs page](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation) for more info

Comment: Yea, I found out that was the case. But I want to know, when this revalidation happen, do they hit the server or they are called from the cache?

Comment: They hit the server, of course, because otherwise it would not get the new data, right? Only the server has potential new data.

Comment: wow, how can something hitting the server that often be cool? Maybe in some situations where it is needed. Maybe